# Sum Columns in Data Frame

Tags: r, sum

I've run into a little problem while trying to summarize my data. Basically for my I'm trying to summarize the diagnoses per Year according to the gender. I've tried to use the aggregate function but the output produced does not provide info for Gender == "UNSPECIFIED"

```
aggregate( cbind(Year.10,Year.11,Year.12,Year.13) ~ Gender, data = dummy , sum)

> Gender Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13
  1 FEMALE 1176290 1113480 1039570 1021810
  2   MALE  674020  783150  571170  588660
```

I've tried to do it with tapply, which shows the UNSPECIFED gender on ouput, but I'm given a NA value for Males and Unspecified.

```
with(dummy, tapply(Year.10, Gender, FUN = sum), na.rm = FALSE)

>  FEMALE        MALE UNSPECIFIED 
  1181980          NA          NA
```

How can I sum the diagnoses per year for each gender? And sum the diagnoses per year of all genders combined?

```
dput(dummy[sample(1:nrow(dummy), 15, replace=FALSE),])                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "factor")), Year.10.1 = c(13700L, 41370L, 52680L, 356070L, 

structure(list(Gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("FEMALE", "MALE", 
"UNSPECIFIED"), class = "factor"), Age = structure(c(4L, 7L, 
7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("0-2", 
"3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP", "0-2", 
"3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP", "3-9", 
"10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP"), class = "factor"), 
Year.10 = c(380610L, 63360L, 111790L, 16900L, 58440L, 484770L, 
13700L, 41520L, 46890L, 80090L, 2470L, 10920L, NA, 5690L, 
NA), Year.11 = c(387080L, 84750L, 84380L, 22380L, 92870L, 
439860L, 2470L, 38460L, 30150L, 76670L, NA, NA, 5590L, NA, 
2150L), Year.12 = c(291930L, 64810L, 123950L, 2260L, 50900L, 
454200L, 7820L, 21550L, 18020L, 92750L, NA, 5500L, NA, NA, 
NA), Year.13 = c(371290L, 79150L, 71890L, 5860L, 84110L, 
412650L, 2100L, 33680L, 19060L, 60710L, NA, 5700L, 11720L, 
NA, NA), Gender.1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("FEMALE", "MALE", 
"UNSPECIFIED"), class = "factor"), Age.1 = structure(c(4L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("0-2", 
"3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Year.10.1 = c(356070L, 52240L, 106280L, 16900L, 
52680L, 460340L, 13700L, 35910L, 41370L, 80090L, NA, NA, 
12850L, NA, 5690L), Year.11.1 = c(372370L, 79200L, 73110L, 
22380L, 87280L, 417800L, 2470L, 38460L, 30150L, 76670L, NA, 
NA, NA, 5590L, NA), Year.12.1 = c(280720L, 59190L, 123950L, 
2260L, 50900L, 447400L, 7820L, 21550L, 18020L, 92750L, 3610L, 
NA, 5560L, NA, NA), Year.13.1 = c(356500L, 62130L, 62110L, 
5860L, 78440L, 395700L, 2100L, 30310L, 19060L, 49240L, NA, 
NA, NA, 11720L, NA)), .Names = c("Gender", "Age", "Year.10", 
"Year.11", "Year.12", "Year.13", "Gender.1", "Age.1", "Year.10.1", 
"Year.11.1", "Year.12.1", "Year.13.1"), row.names = c(4L, 15L, 
7L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 21L, 23L, 19L, 18L, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Head data

```
 Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13 Gender.1 Age.1 Year.10.1 Year.11.1 Year.12.1     Year.13.1
1 FEMALE   0-2   13700    2470    7820    2100   FEMALE   0-2     13700      2470      7820      2100
2 FEMALE   3-9   46890   30150   18020   19060   FEMALE   3-9     41370     30150     18020     19060
3 FEMALE 10-19   58440   92870   50900   84110   FEMALE 10-19     52680     87280     50900     78440
```

Tail data

```
        Gender   Age Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13    Gender.1 Age.1 Year.10.1 Year.11.1 Year.12.1
14        MALE 60-64   54780   54400   47960   40600        MALE 60-64     54780     54400     47960
15        MALE   65+   63360   84750   64810   79150        MALE   65+     52240     79200     59190
16        MALE  UNSP      NA      NA      NA    5670        MALE  UNSP        NA        NA        NA
17 UNSPECIFIED   3-9      NA    2150      NA      NA UNSPECIFIED 10-19      5690        NA        NA
18 UNSPECIFIED 10-19    5690      NA      NA      NA UNSPECIFIED 20-39        NA      5590        NA
19 UNSPECIFIED 20-39      NA    5590      NA   11720 UNSPECIFIED 40-59     12850        NA      5560
20 UNSPECIFIED 40-59   12850      NA    5560      NA UNSPECIFIED 60-64      2470        NA        NA
21 UNSPECIFIED 60-64    2470      NA      NA      NA UNSPECIFIED   65+        NA        NA      3610
22 UNSPECIFIED   65+      NA      NA    3610      NA UNSPECIFIED  UNSP     10920        NA        NA
23 UNSPECIFIED  UNSP   10920      NA    5500    5700 UNSPECIFIED   3-9        NA        NA        NA
```

Comment: @user3900661 It is interesting.  Can you provide an example that has all the levels for `Gender`?  If I change the `dput` data and insert  `dummy$Gender[3:4] <- "MALE"; dummy$Gender[6] <- "UNSPECIFIED"` I get the output for all the levels of `Gender`

Comment: Is the data correct? Seems there are duplicate columns.

Comment: @user3900661 You got `NA` with the `tapply` because in the example dataset, there are no rows for `MALE` and `UNSPECIFIED`.

Comment: @akrun
I can see rows in my dataset that say male and UNSPECIFIED though

Comment: @user3900661 Here is what I get from the `dput` `dummy$Gender
[1] FEMALE FEMALE FEMALE FEMALE FEMALE FEMALE
Levels: FEMALE MALE UNSPECIFIED`  Gender is factor and has 3 levels.  I don't understand your comment though.

Comment: Sorry just woke up, I'm not even sure what I wrote. :p Can you explain to me what is stopping me from using the tapply function?

Comment: @user3900661  It's okay.  Please change the `dput` so that I can look into it.  You can use the `tapply` function if you can apply it to each `Year` column separately.  Otherwise, `aggregate`, `dplyr`, or data.table would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how exactly would you like for me to change the dput? I would use `aggregate` but since it doesn't return the UNSPECIFIED gender data to me it isn't as useful as I would like.

Comment: It looks like you need to restack the data. You have repeating columns that should be two rows and they are presented as one row.  You're likely to get incorrect results unless you stack them

Comment: @user3900661  I guess you used `dput(head(dat, 6))`.  May be you can get a mix of all the levels of Gender.  If `dummy` is your original dataset `dput(dummy[sample(1:nrow(dummy), 15, replace=FALSE),])`

Comment: @user3900661  Could you explain `columns 7 to 12`.  At first, I thought it is the duplicate of 1:6 columns, but it is not.  Also, I am assuming that you want to get the `sum` for only columns 3:6 by Gender.

Comment: Yeah sure `columns 1:6` are number of people who received the diagnoses, col `7:12` are people who received a treatment 

Those columns are going to look similar most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dummy1 <- dummy[,1:6] #subsetting columns 1:6 as it is not about columns 7 to 12

dummy1 %>%
       group_by(Gender) %>%
       summarise_each(funs(sum=sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with("Year"))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

#        Gender Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13
#1      FEMALE 1176290 1113480 1039570 1021810
#2        MALE  121780  145590   88620  118690
#3 UNSPECIFIED   19080    7740    5500   17420
```

Or using `aggregate`

```
 aggregate(dummy1[,3:6], list(Gender=dummy1[,"Gender"]), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
 #        Gender Year.10 Year.11 Year.12 Year.13
 #1      FEMALE 1176290 1113480 1039570 1021810
 #2        MALE  121780  145590   88620  118690
 #3 UNSPECIFIED   19080    7740    5500   17420
```

#### Update

To arrange the `Age`, `Age.1` columns in `dummyN` (the `tail` data)

```
 dummyN$Age.1 <- factor(dummyN$Age.1, levels=c("0-2", "3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP"))
 dummyN$Age<- factor(dummyN$Age, levels=c("0-2", "3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", "65+", "UNSP"))
```

Or you can also use `?ordered` to get ordered factors.

```
  dummyN %>% 
         arrange(Gender, Age, Age.1) %>% #if you need in descending #`arrange(Gender, desc(Age), desc(Age.1))
          select(Gender, Age, Age.1) #just selecting the `Age` columns
   #        Gender   Age Age.1
   #1         MALE 60-64 60-64
   #2         MALE   65+   65+
   #3         MALE  UNSP  UNSP
   #4  UNSPECIFIED   3-9 10-19
   #5  UNSPECIFIED 10-19 20-39
   #6  UNSPECIFIED 20-39 40-59
   #7  UNSPECIFIED 40-59 60-64
   #8  UNSPECIFIED 60-64   65+
   #9  UNSPECIFIED   65+  UNSP
   #10 UNSPECIFIED  UNSP   3-9
```

Comment: Honestly you're a boss! Just one more thing, you might notice in my tail data that ages for the UNSPECIFIED data are not arranged properly. I made dummy:
`dummy <- summy %>%

  arrange(Gender, Age, Age.1)`

Do you have any idea why the Age.1 column does not sort?

Comment: @user3900661 The `Age`, `Age.1` are `character` or `factor` columns.  From the `dput`, it looks like `factor` column.  How do you want to order the `Age` column?  `dummyN$Age [1] "60-64" "65+"   "UNSP"  "3-9"   "10-19" "20-39" "40-59" "60-64" "65+"  
[10] "UNSP"`

Comment: I would like it ordered like this `as.ordered(dummy$Age.1)` 
`Levels: 0-2 < 3-9 < 10-19 < 20-39 < 40-59 < 60-64 < 65+ < UNSP`

Comment: @user3900661 I updated the post.  Actually, I noticed that the `Age` column is ordered in the `tail` data.

Comment: If you look at `row #9` and `Row #10` for unspecified you have the same problem that I encounter in that the age isn't being ordered for Age.1 ie. 10-19 is before 3-9

Comment: @use3900661 It is because the `Age` is already ordered.  I suppose, you don't want to break that `ties` within the rows.

Comment: I think that breaking the ties is what is needed. I can still understand the data afterwards because the values are tied to Ages.

Comment: @user3900661 May be you want to subset the `dummyN` and do `dummyN[,1:6] %>% arrange(Gender, Age);  dummyN[,7:11] %>% arrange(Gender.1, Age.1)` because using `dummyN %>% arrange(Gender, Age, Age.1)` would first order by `Gender, then by `Age`, followed by `Age.1`

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing this and then using the `data.frame` function to merge them again.